# asp Gridview Columns Running Together

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have two adjacent columns that are running together with no space between them. One is a dollar amount and the other a text field containing a name. 
The gridview is defined with CellPadding and CellSpacing so don't expect this.
The column widths are defined as 6% and 12% respectively. The total of the width definitions of the columns is 70%.

Any suggestions?
[Running Together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEyOk.jpg)

[Grid Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTKnX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be easier for the GridView header to be posted as plain text instead of an image. If I wanted to test your GridView I would have to type the code instead of copy/paste.
But the issue is probably css, or the lack thereof. It seems that the value is aligned to the right, but the padding is not applied. Which can happen is a BootStrap is used.
So create your own style for the GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="MyGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="FloatRight">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Amount") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Description") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<style>
    .MyGrid td {
        padding: 3px;
    }

    .MyGrid .FloatRight {
        float: right;
    }
</style>
```